# why does change in data doesn't change the plot line?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am new to machine learning and i am building a simple linear regession model. The variables for the model are as follows:

```
X_train = [3, 5, 3, 4, 8, 7, 1, 10, 3, 2, 6, 6, 4, 9, 2, 1, 7, 5, 4, 8]
X_test = [2, 10, 4, 4, 10, 9, 10, 4, 5, 8]
Y_train = [56642, 66029, 64445, 61111, 113812, 91738, 46205, 121872, 60150, 39891, 81363, 93940, 57189, 54445, 105582, 43525, 39343, 98273, 67938, 56957]
Y_test = [37731, 122391, 57081, 63218, 116969, 109431, 112635, 55794, 83088, 101302]
```

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 1/3, random_state = 0)


#fitting simple linear regression on training sets
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

#predicting the test set results
y_pred = np.array(regressor.predict(X_test))
```

And here's my code for plotting the graph:

```
#visualizing data for the test set
plt.scatter(X_test, y_test, color = 'red')

#Method 1: Using regressor.predict(X_train)
plt.plot(X_train,regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'green')

#Method 2: Using regressor.predict(X_test)
plt.plot(X_test, regressor.predict(X_test), color='yellow')

plt.title('Experience v/s Salary')
plt.xlabel('Experience')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()
```

Here's the image of my graph:

[image: Image for the question]

Why am i getting the same regression line for both `plt.plot(X_train,regressor.predict(X_train), color = 'green')` and `plt.plot(X_test, regressor.predict(X_test), color='yellow')` even though i am getting different results for `regressor.predict(X_train)` and `regressor.predict(X_test)`?

Comment: `len` of `X_train` and `Y_train` is mismatching

Comment: Your sample data is ill-formed. `X_train` has 19 elements and `Y_train` has 20, and `X_train` and `X_test` should be nested `lists`. Also, you should include images of your plots.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Akhilesh that is a typing error. I have not created the dataset but downloaded it.  I just divided the dataset into training and test sets using ```train_test_split```

Comment: @gmds why should X_train and X_test be nested lists? I have divided the data into training and test sets using the ```train_test_split```. Also,  the course I'm following nowhere tells me that both these arrays need to be nested for the model to work. So it'd be helpful if you can provide further details.

Comment: @SamarthSaxena That's what `sklearn` expects; one axis represents rows, and the other represents columns. Try running `fit` on your `X_train` and `y_train` as they are right now (after removing one value from `y_train`) to make their shapes compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A LinearRegression model literally just learns a straight line. For any input it will map the output to a point on that straight line. You get the same line as, no matter the input, you will always get a point on that line!

Have a look at `regressor.intercept_` and `regressor.coef` after fitting, this will show the intercept on the y axis (probably around 36000 from that graph), and the gradient of the line (probably 10000 maybe?).

Comment: Correct me if i'm getting it wrong. So the regressor will take any input value and mark the y coordinate according to the slope of the line without changing the slope. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, exactly right. In your case (I believe) it takes the Experience value, multiples by the coefficient (_m_, the gradient), and adds the intercept (_c_, where it crosses the y axis). In this way all x values are mapped onto this line, whether they are train or test. To change the slope you need to retrain the model with different data.

Answer (score 0):

because we usually `train` our `model` on train data. and `model learns` from `train data only` and we assume `test data` is a `sample` which is very similar to `train data` only. and we apply `predict` on it.

In your scenario, there is only one model `regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)` and it has its `intercept` and `slope` and it is fixed. (in simple words there is a line which will not change it can only expand in its direction even a random unknown sample will make a line which will overlap your yellow and green line)